# We have a map $g : \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $. What is the kernel of $g$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have a map $g : \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ given by $g(x+24\mathbb{Z}) = (x + 6\mathbb{Z}, x + 4\mathbb{Z})$.

What is the kernel of $g $? 
In other words, which elements of $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ get mapped by $g$ to the zero element of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Which elements of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are in the image of g ?

I need help with this all. I am completely stuck/confused.

Comment: What is the kernel of $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$? Can you describe the kernels of the individual projections $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$? How do we put those two pieces of information together?

Comment: These are all questions I need help answering.

Comment: What is the kernel of $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, first?

Comment: Just to re-state blue's question. You need to ask yourselve what it means for an element to be zero in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (in  particular for $n\in[4,6]$). If you know this, then you are as good as done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar example that might help you:

Consider the map $\pi:\mathbb{Z}/40\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ given by $[n]_{40} \mapsto ([n]_4,[n]_{10}),$ where here $[n]_m$ denotes the equivalence class of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. I'll leave it up to you to check this is well defined (you've probably done this already in a more general context). We determine the kernel of $\pi$ as follows:

$$[n]_{40} \in \ker \pi \iff \pi([n]_{40})=e \iff ([n]_4,[n]_{10})=([0]_4,[0]_{10}) $$ $$\iff [n]_4 =[0]_4 \text{ and } [n]_{10}=[0]_{10}.$$

Since $[n]_m=[0]_m$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $m$ divides $n$, the above argument yields that $[n]_{40} \in \ker \pi$ if and only if $4$ divides $n$ and $10$ divides $n$. Now you should be able to concisely characterize the kernel of my homomorphism, and adapt the argument to your problem.

More generally, it's useful to note the following. If $\phi: G \rightarrow H_1 \times H_2$ is a group homomorphism, then $\phi = \phi_1 \times \phi_2$ for $\phi_i : G \rightarrow H_i$. That is, $\phi(g)=(\phi_1(g),\phi_2(g))$ for any $g \in G$. It's easy to show that the kernel of $\phi$ is the intersection of the kernel of $\phi_1$ and the kernel of $\phi_2$. You can check that this holds for the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Your map can be built from the obvious homomorphism $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}f:\Z\to\Z/6\Z\times\Z/4\Z$ defined by
$$
f(x)=(x+6\Z,x+4\Z)
$$
The kernel of this homomorphism is easily computed: $f(x)=(0+6\Z,0+4\Z)$ if and only if $x\in 6\Z\cap 4\Z=12\Z$.

Since $24\Z\subseteq 12\Z$, $f$ induces a homomorphism $\Z/24\Z\to\Z/6\Z\times\Z/4\Z$ which is just your $g$. The kernel is then $12\Z/24\Z$. Also the image of $g$ is the same as the image of $f$.

**Theorem.** If $f\colon G\to G'$ is a group homomorphism and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with $H\subseteq\ker f$, then there is a unique homomorphism $g\colon G/H\to G'$ such that $f=g\circ\pi$, where $\pi:G\to G/H$ is the canonical projection. The kernel of $g$ is $\ker f/H$ and the image of $g$ equals the image of $f$.